# Save PDF by using Selenium and IE Browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer

To save PDF by using CHrome Browser does not cause any issues (I'm using these options):

```
    options.add_experimental_option('prefs',{
    'credentials_enable_service': False,
    'plugins':{
        'always_open_pdf_externally': True
    },
    'profile': {
        'password_manager_enabled': False,
    },
    'download': {
        'prompt_for_download': False,
        'directory_upgrade': True,
        'default_directory': ''
    }
})
```

BUT .... How to save PDF by using `webdriver.Ie()` Internet Explorer Driver with Python + Selenium?

P.S. AFAIK Internet explorer can not be executed by using headless mode, but if someone will not the way to do it, will be amazing !!!

Comment: Hi, is there any update about the issue? May I know if you have any chance to check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Selenium to deal with the download prompt in IE because that's an OS-level prompt. Selenium WebDriver has no capability to automate OS-level prompt window. You need to use some 3rd party tools to help you to download file in IE using Selenium.

Here I use **[Wget](https://eternallybored.org/misc/wget/)** to bypass the download prompt and download file in IE. You can refer to [this article](https://www.guru99.com/upload-download-file-selenium-webdriver.html) about how to use Wget.

About using headless mode in IE in Selenium, you can also use a 3rd party tool called [**headless_ie_selenium**](https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win). You can download this tool and use headless_ie_selenium.exe instead of IEDriverServer.exe to automate IE.

The sample code to download a pdf file is like below, please note to change the paths in the code to your owns:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import os

url = "https://file-examples.com/index.php/sample-documents-download/sample-pdf-download/"
driver = webdriver.Ie('D:\\headless-selenium-for-win-v1-4\\headless_ie_selenium.exe')
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

link = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("download-button")[0]
hrefurl = link.get_attribute("href")

os.system('cmd /c C:\\Wget\\wget.exe -P D:\\Download --no-check-certificate ' + hrefurl)

print("*******************")
```

Comment: The problem is, it is fine to do your way , but in some edge cases you can't even press CTRL + S to save opened/generated PDF, and there is no href link to simply download it... But thank you for your answer, in some cases "No, you can't" is still an answer :D