# Headless IE driver for Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer

I developed an automation application  for a website in Intranet to make my job quicker. Then, we decided to move my app to server on Intranet for everyone to use.

In my application, I used selenium in c# and Microsoft Edge in IE mode because website we automated only properly work with IE.

Now I need to use IE in headless mode so, it can run properly in server. But, IE does not support headless mode also, Edge and Chrome in IE mode.

I checked PhamtomJS driver does not work for me. TrifleJS is given as an answer in some questions but it does not work as selenium webdriver that what I can understand from [here](https://github.com/sdesalas/trifleJS/issues/20)

So, is there any way to make IE work in headless mode? As I mentioned above I can not use Edge or chrome so, they are not a solution in my case.

Regards.

Comment: Maybe try a scheduled task to invoke your selenium script? You can run those as a user who has a desktop available. Then you can run IE with a window.

Comment: You can use a 3rd party tool called [headless_ie_selenium](https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win) to use headless mode in IE in Selenium. For more information, you can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67500000/save-pdf-by-using-selenium-and-ie-browser/67514738#comment119636055_67514738).